# ContainerSASPermissions not exported from Azure Storage Blob

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am getting a wierd import Error:

```
./src/components/pages/DocumentationPage.tsx
Attempted import error: 'ContainerSASPermissions' is not exported from '@azure/storage-blob'.
```

This is the way it is implemented in the azure docs in GitHub: [list-blobs-from-container-sas-token](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureStorageSnippets/blob/master/blobs/howto/JavaScript/NodeJS-v12/dev-guide/list-blobs-from-container-sas-token.js)

I have already installed the package `"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.12.0"` which lies under dependencies in the `package.json` file.

You can also see in the Screenshot, that the package is already downloaded locally.

Do I have to update my tsconfig.json or a path?

As an info the project is new, but other packages, such as the [@tanstack/react-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanstack/react-query)
 are working without a problem.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

To create SAS token at container level using Typescript,
you can use this **[MS-DOCUMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/storage-blob-typescript/)**

Before running the samples in Node, install typescript compiler:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

For working with azure-blob-storage and azure-identity:

```
 npm install @azure/storage-blob
 npm install @azure/identity
```

**Code(demo.ts):**

```
import {BlobServiceClient,
ContainerSASPermissions,
generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
SASProtocol,ContainerClient} from "@azure/storage-blob";

import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

async  function  createContainerSas(){

// Get environment variables
const  accountName = "venkat123";
const  containerName = "test";


const  TEN_MINUTES = 10 * 60 * 1000;
const  NOW = new  Date();
const  TEN_MINUTES_BEFORE_NOW = new  Date(NOW.valueOf() - TEN_MINUTES);
const  TEN_MINUTES_AFTER_NOW = new  Date(NOW.valueOf() + TEN_MINUTES);

// Best practice: use managed identity - DefaultAzureCredential

const  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClient(
 `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  new  DefaultAzureCredential()
);


// Best practice: delegation key is time-limited

// When using a user delegation key, container must already exist
const  userDelegationKey = await  blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(
TEN_MINUTES_BEFORE_NOW,
TEN_MINUTES_AFTER_NOW
);
// Best practice: SAS options are time-limited
const  sasOptions = {
containerName,
permissions:  ContainerSASPermissions.parse("c"),
protocol:  SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp,
startsOn:  TEN_MINUTES_BEFORE_NOW,
expiresOn:  TEN_MINUTES_AFTER_NOW
};
const  sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
sasOptions,
userDelegationKey,
accountName
).toString();

console.log(`SAS token for blob container is: ${sasToken}`);
return  `${ContainerClient.url}?${sasToken}`;
}
createContainerSas()
```

**Console:**

[image]

To check the **`SAS-token`** at container level, I execute the below command in browser.

**Command:**

```
https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/test1?restype=container&comp=list&<SAS token>
```

**Browser:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailled answer. Nevertheless, it is not clear to me, in which way your approach is different to mine. Also what do you mean with "Before running the samples in Node"? I am trying to build only for the client.

Comment: Please refer this Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/storage-blob-typescript/